# Using WITH... AS (CTE) within a Postgres Function

Tags: sql, postgresql

in all the below descriptions, I have changed the names of variables, functions and datasets so as to make it easier for you to follow the code. What I want to do is create a new function, myFx, which takes in an argument of var_a and outputs a table with 3 columns - var_a, var_b and var_c.

The code is shown below, the bulk of which is a Common Table Expression (CTE) that uses UNION to combine the rows from three SELECT statements to make an interim table result, t_union. The lowermost chunk of code is the one which outputs what I desire through using t_union and self-joining it to itself.

While the paragraphs of code below work WITHOUT me typing the function parameters (CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION... and RETURNS TABLE...), once I add the function parameters in, I instead get an error indicating that I cannot use WITH as in (WITH t_union). Could anyone please advise me what the problem is here? Thanks so much!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFx (var_a varchar(2))

RETURNS TABLE (var_a varchar(2),
    var_b character,
    var_c character )

WITH t_union
AS (SELECT x, y, z,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY (y COLLATE "C") ASC) AS stp_pos
    FROM DATASET1

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT x, y, z,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY (y COLLATE "C") ASC) AS stp_pos
    FROM DATASET2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT x, y, z,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY (y COLLATE "C") ASC) AS stp_pos
    FROM DATASET3

SELECT BS.atoc_code, L1.train_uid, L1.stp_indicator, L1.location AS loc1, L2.location AS loc2
    FROM t_union L1 JOIN t_union L2
    ON L1.x=L2.x AND L1.y<L2.y
    JOIN DATASET3 BS ON L1.x=BS.x;
```

This is the error code I get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"
LINE 9: WITH t_union
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 197
```

Comment: Perhaps you need a `begin` or something similar.

Comment: Look at the documentation to see the basic syntax for `CREATE FUNCTION`.

Comment: You need a bracket to close the CTE, after `FROM DATASET3`.